# add student object to sorted array by name

Tags: java

i need to add Student in Group class to Student array that sorted by the name
also need to be in low complexity(O(n) or O(n^2)

```
public void add(String name,int day,int month,int year)
{  
   if(_noOfStud==MAX_STUDENTS)
      return;

   else if(_noOfStud==0)
       _stud[_noOfStud]=new Student(name,day,month,year);

   else...........?

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Arrays.binarySearch

```
Object[] studenArray = new Object[2];

Object studentObj = new Object();

int position = Arrays.binarySearch(studenArray, studentObj, new Comparator<Object>() {

    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        return o1.toString().compareTo(o2.toString());
    }
});
```

position will be the student position if there is a student with same name
the position will return negative number -1 = possible position 0, -2 = 1

for more info see [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(T[],%20T,%20java.util.Comparator))